# Frequency of non-unique instances while conditioning on groups within and across data frames

Tags: r, data-binding, unique, aggregation, conditional-operator

I am analyzing employment data containing information about the firms that individuals worked for in a given year, with each year being a separate data frame.

I want to be able to quickly identify individuals that have worked for multiple firms in a given year, as well as individuals who have worked for multiple firms in one year. My goal is to calculate some frequency for the number of times a given firm experiences "exit" (an employee changing firms) both within-year (a single data frame) and across years.

The data frame(s) are structured as follows:

```
year1 <- data.frame(individual=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "2", "6", "7", "3", "9", "10"),
                firm=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "D", "B", "B", "C"))

year2 <- data.frame(individual=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"),
                firm=c("A", "B", "D", "D", "A", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C"))
```

I am fairly certain how to do this within a given year, by searching for all the non-unique associations between individuals and firms, but am at a loss for how to do this over multiple data objects/years. Again, I am interested in the frequency of "exit" for the firm rather than the specific individual.

My ideal output would be frequency/proportion of total employees of each firm as follows:

```
exit(withinyear)_byfirm
exit(betweenyear)_byfirm
```

Answer (score 0):

Count, not proportion:

```
within <- function(y) {
  # A vector of length > 1 in the aggregate function means that the person has
  # changed jobs.
  # `[` ignores the value 0 if there are other values present, and returns a
  # zero-length vector if not.  Often a source of confusion, but perfect here.
  table(levels(y$firm)[aggregate(firm~individual, data=y,
                                 function(x) {z<- unique(x)                 
                                              if(length(z) > 1) head(z, -1) else 0})$firm])
}

between <- function(year1, year2) {
  # Last place worked in year1
  y1 <- rbind(do.call(rbind, by(year1, year1$individual, FUN=tail, 1)))

  # First place worked in year2
  y2 <- rbind(do.call(rbind, by(year2, year2$individual, FUN=head, 1)))

  # Combine these and look for duplicate individuals with the prior function
  y <- rbind(y1, y2)
  within(y)
}
```

The results:

```
> within(year1)

B C 
1 1 

> within(year2)
character(0)

> between(year1, year2)

A B 
1 1
```

Comment: Two errors:
within(year1)
Error in levels(y$firm)[aggregate(firm ~ individual, data = y, function(x) { : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'

There appears to be some sort of indexing issue when aggregating? It's attempting to sort a list rather than an index? Am I correct?

between(year1,year2,year3,year4,year5)
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

I think this has to do with the fact that some individuals are repeated across years while others are not, a classic issue with panel data/retention.

Comment: Very odd.  I get no errors with R 2.15.2.  Also, the `between` shown above only takes two arguments.  You need more?

Comment: Yes, but I used your example and modified the arguments to include all 5 yearly data sets.

Comment: I have 2.15.1 installed elsewhere.  I'll try this code later today, and see what happens.

Comment: I think there is some specific problem with the argumentation for the within(y) portion of the between() function for multiple years (more than 2).

I took this piece of code out and was able to output the rbind() of all the yearly data to check it manually.